# await does not work but .Result does in Xamarin app

Tags: .net, xamarin, async-await, xamarin.ios

I'm giving my first try on iOS develop with Xamarin and I'm facing a weird problem. I wanna do an async call on a HTTP request using a simple, plain HttpClient GetStringAsync call. When I run the app on the simulator the screen gets blank and stop to respond. The actual code for the call:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var res = await client.GetStryngAsync("https://anyurl.com");
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(res);
```

If I set a breakpoint on the `return` line, the debugger never hits. Instead, this code works perfectly:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var res = client.GetStringAsync("https://anyurl.com").Result;
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(res);
```

Even if I change the `.Result` with a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` the debugger hits but the app keeps blank.

I tried changing the http call with a plain `await Task.Delay(1000)` and the problem is still there.

I checked the HttpClient implementation, tried to install the ModernHttpClient package, Internet Connection permission in the .plist file and I have no clue what's the problem, but I'm started to think that it has something to do with the async/await part. Running the app with VS for Mac or with Jetbrains Rider makes no difference.

Thank you in advance.

#### Edit to expand the question

I'm using the MVVMCross framework in this project, and I have this code in my MainViewModel Initialize method:

```
public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        await base.Initialize();

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var res = await client.GetStringAsync("https://myurl.com");
        var a = 1;
    }
```

If I put the breakpoint at line 5, there is no problem with the `await base.Initialize()` call, but if I put the breakpoint at line 7 the debugger never hits and the app goes blank. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you post the full method signature and calling code?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I updated the question with the code and more info trying to be clearer

Comment: This is a known issue with Initialize in the ViewModel you launch as the Root ViewModel. Instead, I suggest you use one of the Lifecycle methods to trigger a command.